# Python 3: Asterisk in print function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's have a look:

```
print([object, ...], *, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout)
```

http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print

How can we interpret that `'*'`? 
Usually an asterisk ('*') means numerous objects. But herein it is a mystery to me. Between two commas... I'm even afraid to think it may be a typo.

Answer (score 15):

That's an error in the documentation, inserted by someone applying a new Python 3 feature to places where it shouldn't be used. It has since been fixed (see [issue 15831](http://bugs.python.org/issue15831)).

The function signatures in the document used is given in a psuedo-formal-grammar form, but adding in the `*` marker only makes sense if you use actual python syntax. The `[object, ...], *` part of the signature should have been listed as `*objects` instead in that case.

The corrected version now reads:

> `print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)`

The online [development version of the documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#print) has as of now not yet been updated, but the [documentation source has been corrected](http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/b01eb870f84f#l4.49); I'll see if we can request a regeneration of the docs.

To be clear: the `*` syntax is valid in Python 3 and means that the following arguments can only ever be used as keyword arguments, not positional arguments. This does however *not* apply to the `print()` function, as *all* positional arguments are to be printed anyway and could never be mistaken for the keyword arguments.

Comment: the asterisk `*` still means (in addition to passing all positional parameters as `objects`) that the following arguments should be supplied using their names i.e., my answer is valid.

Comment: Pardon, please. But where can I see that the bug has been fixed? I provided you with the acute link. The bug is still here. As for help in the command line, that is help(print), it types: print(value, ..., sep=' ', end ='\n', file = sys.stdout). So, again I don't know how to interpret it. What 'value' means as compared to 'object'.

Comment: Then what '...' between two commas means. So, somehow I can't understand this function thoroughly.

Comment: @Kifsif: Yes, the online documentation needs to be regenerated still. The dev version also still contains the incorrect text. I linked you to the bug report, which has been marked as fixed because the documentation source has been updated. I pulled the corrected version from the bug report. The `...` between the two commas was part of the incorrectly generated method signature.

Answer (score 13):

It means that the following arguments are keyword-only i.e., you can't supply them as positional arguments, you must use their names e.g.:

```
>>> def f(*, a): pass
... 
>>> f(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() takes exactly 0 positional arguments (1 given)
>>> f(a=1)
>>> # ok
```

Another example:

```
>>> def g(*a, b): pass
... 
>>> g(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: g() needs keyword-only argument b
>>> g(1, 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: g() needs keyword-only argument b
>>> g(1, b=2)
>>> # ok
>>> g(1, 2, b=3)
>>> # ok
```

Comment: No, it means the documentation was generated wrong; the `, *` is caused by a doc tools bug.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: try: `def f(a, *,b): pass` and see whether you'll be able to supply `b` as a positional argument

Comment: Sebastian is right, the arguments following a * can only be given as names arguments. It's a new feature in Python 3.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: That's a nice cool thing too, but not what the OP was asking about. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters: The opposite is true. The bug you cited is irrelevant. Before/after docs describe the same thing (except for new in 3.3 `flush` argument): `print()` accepts zero or more positional arguments to be printed and keyword-only arguments that specify printing options with their default values.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Sure, but the `*` was a distraction and the syntax confusing. Using an actual legal python function signature makes it much clearer what the function accepts; the `[object, ...], *` syntax was an obscure mixture of pseudo-formal-grammar and  an overzealous application of the `*` marker in the documentation where it was not needed.